# How to use SafeHtml annotation on dto properties?

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, dto

I have a dto which is taken from another API (decompiled class) and in that dto one string field is tagged as SafeHtml to prevent users to inject HTML scripts.

```
@NotNull
@SafeHtml(
    whitelistType = WhiteListType.NONE,
    groups = {Default.class}
)
@ApiModelProperty(
    value = "The label of customer",
    required = true
)
private String label;
```

But when i send request via postman or from frontend -e.g `<script>alert('blabla')</script>`- it still accepts this input and executes.

What seems wrong here? Other working examples are own dto class of the project but in this example this dto is a decompiled class from another api, so can it be the reason for it? (I don't think so because this dto's api is also accepting it) so what is wrong?

Or is only specifying SafeHtml not enough and do I need to do something more?

Edit: my controller is:

```
        @PostMapping("customer/save")
            @ApiOperation("Adds customer")
            public ResponseEntity<CustomerDto> saveCustomer(
                    @ApiParam("Customers to save") @RequestBody CustomerDti customerDto) {

    return ResponseEntity.ok(customerService.saveCustomer(customerDto);
}
```

And note: if i put safehtml on my model class, it works but i do not want it. I want to reject the request immediately whenever it comes so i need to disable it on dto class.

Comment: Validator constraints annotations are validated "on demand" or by specifying it in the rest controller for example `@Valid` . Post your controller if it doesn't address your issue.

Comment: @davidxxx  i didnt understand. i added my controller

Comment: added an answer to illustrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said, constraint annotations are validated "on demand".
In your case you have to add the `@Valid` annotation to valid the request :

```
@PostMapping("customer/save")
@ApiOperation("Adds customer")
public ResponseEntity<CustomerDto> saveCustomer(
        @ApiParam("Customers to save") @RequestBody @Valid CustomerDti customerDto) {

  return ResponseEntity.ok(customerService.saveCustomer(customerDto);
}
```